# $p(x)$ be a fifth degree polynomial with integer coeffients that has an integral root $\alpha$. If $p(2)=13$ and $p(10)=5$

Tags: polynomials, roots

> $p(x)$ be a fifth degree polynomial with integer coeffients that has an integral root $\alpha$. If $p(2)=13$ and $p(10)=5$ then find the value of $\alpha$

I am looking for various other approaches to this problem

Thanks !

Comment: You better add your solution to the body of the question and ask for different approaches.

Comment: I think the argument you give is too terse for someone to follow.  That said, you give the correct answer and, guessing at the pieces you left out, I'd say that method was probably optimal.

Comment: @VIVID , done , thank for the suggestion

Comment: Why do you need a different approach? Is there any problem with this solution or does it ignore any restriction in the problem statement?

Comment: @lulu I was just looking for different ways of thinking in this or similar problems , it's not that the solution has to be smaller.

Comment: But I think that any solution will be more or less equivalent to this one.  It isn't true, for example, that the value of $a$ is always determined by two values of the polynomial.  That's an accident, determined by the list of divisors of the two values.  I don't think you can avoid going through those divisors.

Comment: @VIVID I wanted different approaches just to lnowore ways to solve this , it's not that this solution has anything wrong with it .

Comment: @lulu I think you're right . I think I'll just post my solution as answer and let it be here , for if someone else would like to see it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that $a-b$ divides $p(a)-p(b)$ for all integers $a$ and $b$.

$\alpha -2$ divides $0-13$ and so $\alpha -2 \in \{-13,-1,1,13 \}$.

$\alpha -10$ divides $0-5$ and so $\alpha -10 \in \{-5,-1,1,5 \}$.

Therefore, $\alpha \in \{ -11,1,3,15 \} \cap \{ 5,9,11,15 \} = \{ 15 \}$.

Answer (score 0):

The polynomial will have a factor $(x-\alpha)$ , and it will be an integer for integral values of $x$ , now 13 and 5 can be factored as $\pm13\times \pm1$ and $\pm5\times \pm1$ , after checking various possible combinations. Only value of $\alpha$ which satisfies both the given conditions is 15

So , $\alpha=15$